# How to make networkx edge label "hitbox" transparant?

Tags: python, plot, networkx, edges

How can one reduce the size of the white space around an edge label in networkx, or even make it fully transparent whilst preserving the edge weight font size?

As an example of the behaviour, one can look at edge-weight `-24` from node `rand_1_1` to node `degree_receiver_2_1_1`, which also interferes with the edge from the node `degree_receiver_0_1_0` to node `degree_receiver_2_1_1` (even though the `-24` does not really touch that edge):
[image]

To create the edge weights in the first place I am using the following function:

```py
def get_edge_labels(node_labels_dict:Dict,snn_graph:nx.DiGraph,pos:Any):
    """Sets the edge labels. pos is node position."""
    edge_labels:Dict={}
    
    # Get the synaptic weights per node.
    for edge in snn_graph.edges:
        edgeweight=snn_graph.edges[edge]["synapse"].weight
        
        # Create dictionary with synaptic weights.
        edge_labels[edge]=edgeweight
        
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(snn_graph, pos, labels=node_labels_dict)
    
    # TODO: Set edge weight positions per edge to non-overlapping positions.
    # TODO: Make edge weight "hitbox" transparant.
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(snn_graph, pos, edge_labels, font_size=5, label_pos=0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background is specified by the `bbox` parameter. The default is `{boxstyle=’round’, ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)}`. To make the box transparent, supply an additional `alpha` parameter set to zero: `{boxstyle=’round’, ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), alpha=0}`, i.e.:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(snn_graph, ..., bbox={boxstyle=’round’, ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), alpha=0})
```